# React Router 4 - Controlled Component not Un-Mounting on Switch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I'm trying to learn how to lift the state from `<Child/>` to `<Parent/>` and have the **parent** control user interactions done the **child**, (which receives state down as a prop) i.e show color and text.

I was able to lift the state up. However, when I **switch** back and forth between routes the `<Parent/>` component is not re-mounting and its state remains exactly how it was previously set by `setState({})`

```
const cars = [
  { name: "Ferrari", cost: "$9.000", color: "red", id: 1 },
  { name: "Porsche", cost: "$8.000", color: "black", id: 2 },
  ***
];

class Dealership extends Component {
  state = {
    cars,
    isShow: {},
    correctIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * (cars.length - 1))
  };

  handleShuffle = () => {
    this.setState({
      cars: [...this.state.cars.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)],
      isShow: {}
    });
  };

  handleShow = car => {
    const { isShow } = this.state;
    console.log("isShow=", isShow);

    this.setState(currentState => ({
      isShow: { ...currentState.isShow, [car]: true }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navigation />
        <Routes
          state={this.state}
          shuffle={this.handleShuffle}
          handleShow={this.handleShow}
          // isShow={this.state.isShow}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Dealership);
```

As mentioned above, the **child** `<Car/>`is receiving state down as props so that its user interaction can be controlled by one source of truth the **parent** `<Dealership />`

```
export default class Car extends Component {
  render() {
    const { cars, shuffle, isShow, handleShow, correctIndex } = this.props;
    const correctCar = cars[correctIndex];

    const car = cars.map(car => (
      <CarList
        // {...this.state}
        isShow={isShow[car.name]}
        key={car.id}
        car={car.name}
        guess={car.cost}
        isCorrect={correctCar.cost === car.cost}
        handleShow={handleShow}
      />
    ));

    return (
      <>
        <Question key={correctCar.id} guess={correctCar.cost} />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            shuffle();
          }}
        >
          go again
        </button>
        <ul className="car-list">{car}</ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

The `<CarList/>` is abstracted here:

```
// CarList.js
export const CarList = ({ isShow, isCorrect, car, handleShow, guess }) => {
  function getColor() {
    if (isShow) {
      const showColor = isCorrect ? "green" : "red";
      return showColor;
    }
    return "";
  }
  return (
    <li onClick={() => handleShow(car)} className={getColor()}>
      {car}
      <span className={isShow ? "show" : "hide"}>{guess}</span>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Oddly (to me), when I switch to a route that holds its own local state i.e `<Bike/>`, everything works as expected (the state is back to original)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export const Bike = () => {
  const [color, setColor] = useState(false);

  function ChangeColor() {
    setColor(true);
  }
  return (
    <p onClick={ChangeColor}>
      Click on the <span className={color ? "red" : " "}>Bike</span>
    </p>
  );
};
```

This is how I have my Routes setup:

```js
// Navigation.JS
export const Navigation = () => (
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/car-cost">car</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/bike">bike</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
);

// Routes.js
export const Routes = ({ state, shuffle, handleShow, isShow }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path="/car-cost"
      render={() => (
        <Car
          {...state}
          shuffle={shuffle}
          handleShow={handleShow}
          // isShow={isShow}
        />
      )}
    />
    <Route path="/bike" render={() => <Bike />} />
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
  </Switch>
);
```

I then wrapped my main app with `<BrowserRouter />`  as you see in totality plus the current misbehavior happening on this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/01jk7jrl3p)

**How can I switch between routes** having `<Car/>` behave such as `<Bike/>`? i.e *return to its original state*. Also, **am I lifting and controlling state correctly here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the state are being saved in parent component. When the route changes then only child components are being remounted. So the state of parent component remains there throughout that routing.

You can keep the state in child component, which would reset the state after every unmount. However if you want to lift the state up and still reset the state, then you would have to do that in parent component.

A better way would be to monitor the route change in the parent component. If the route has changed then parent component should reset its state. In `componentDidUpdate` method of parent component, you can track the route change and reset the state like this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      console.log('Route change! Reset the state');
      this.setState({ isShow: {}})
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight Prakash. Cld you show me how a reset function would be implemented on that case?

Comment: @Jonca33 I think the better way would be to track the route change in parent component itself. Check the answer.

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Prakash! Where do you recommend me learning more about such approach that you've suggested i. e `props.location.pathname`?

Comment: `location.pathname` is related to react router. You can read about that in their docs.